# PhpSpreadsheet not correctly populating data from array into Excel file

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I have an array containing multiple subarrays, where each subarray represents a record with various data fields. When I print the array using print_r, the output appears to be correct, showing the expected structure and values.

Here's an example of the array structure I have:

```
    // Example array structure:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Vertrekken 2023] => check
            // Other data fields for the record...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Vertrekken 2023] => check
            // Other data fields for the record...
        )

    // More records...
)
```

However, when I try to dump this array into an Excel file using PhpSpreadsheet, the data does not populate correctly. The resulting Excel file does not match the expected structure, and the values are not in the correct columns.

I am getting the data from web scrapping and there is no issue with that, the only issue is with for the data to be populated into the file correctly, thanks in advance.

I am using the following code to populate the Excel file:

```
<?php
//Require the PhpSpreadsheet library
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

// Read the CSV file
//$csvFile = 'links.csv';
//$csvData = array_map('str_getcsv', file($csvFile));

$csvFile = 'links.csv'; // Replace with the path to your CSV file

$data = array();

if (($handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r')) !== false) {
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
$arr = array();

// Display the array
foreach($data as $datas => $key){
    foreach($key as $value){
        if($value == "") {
            
        } else {
        $arr[] = $value;
        }
    }
}

// Iterate over each link in the CSV
foreach ($arr as $url) {
     // Assuming the link is in the first column

    // Get the HTML content from the URL
    $html = file_get_contents($url);

    // // Create a new DOMDocument object
    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    // Configure libxml to handle HTML errors
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

    // Load the HTML content
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    
    // Clear libxml error buffer
    libxml_clear_errors();

    // // Find the table element with class "responsive-table"
    $tableElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
    foreach ($tableElements as $table) {
        if ($table->getAttribute('class') === 'responsive-table') {
            // Create an array to store the table data
            $tableData = array();

            // Find all table rows
            $rows = $table->getElementsByTagName('tr');

            // Process the header row to extract column names
            $headerRow = $rows->item(0);
            $headerCells = $headerRow->getElementsByTagName('th');
            $columns = array();
            foreach ($headerCells as $headerCell) {
                $columns[] = trim($headerCell->nodeValue);
            }

            // Iterate over each row starting from the second row
            for ($i = 1; $i < $rows->length; $i++) {
                $rowData = array();
                $row = $rows->item($i);

                // Find all table cells in the row
                $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');

                // Iterate over each cell and store the data
                foreach ($cells as $j => $cell) {
                    $rowData[$columns[$j]] = trim($cell->nodeValue);
                }

                // Add the row data to the table data array
                $tableData[] = $rowData;
            }

            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($tableData);
            echo '</pre>';

            
            // Create a new Spreadsheet object
            $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
            $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

            // Set the header row
            foreach ($columns as $key => $column) {
                $columnLetter = chr(65 + $key);
                $sheet->setCellValue($columnLetter . '1', $column);
            }

            // Set the data rows
            foreach ($tableData as $rowKey => $row) {
                $rowNumber = $rowKey + 2;
                foreach ($row as $columnKey => $cellValue) {
                    // $columnLetter = chr(65 + (int)$columnKey + 1);
                    // $sheet->setCellValue($columnLetter . $rowNumber, $cellValue);
                    $columnLetter = chr(65 + (int)$columnKey);
                    $columnIndex = (int)$columnKey + 1;
                    // $sheet->setCellValue($columnLetter . $rowNumber, $cellValue);
                    $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($columnIndex, $rowNumber, $cellValue);
                }
            }

            // Generate a unique filename based on the link
            $filename = 'scraped_data_' . md5($url) . '.xlsx';

            // Save the spreadsheet to an Excel file
            $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
            $writer->save($filename);

            echo 'Data has been saved to ' . $filename . '<br>';

            break; // Stop processing further tables
        }
    }
}
```